# How do I use the mallets in 3D Classics: Kid Icarus?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, kid-icarus

I'm on the second area of the first stage of [3D Classics: Kid Icarus](http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/Jh-8m_ayxVBEk4JRbFVlOY1CThV5Nm1H). I've collected 13 items which the manual identifies as mallets; it says that I can use them as weapons by pressing Y to switch weapons. However, pressing Y does nothing; my attack button continues to shoot arrows. Is this an ability which is enabled later? Do I need to do something else? Am I misunderstanding the controls?

In the Controls menu I have checked that the Y button (as well as the L and R buttons) are set to Weapon Selection. My Y button functions normally in other games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mallets can only be used in fortress stages (the final part of each world).

They can be used to attack enemies, although they're not very good at it. Their main purpose is to smash centurion statues, who then join you during the fortress's boss fight.

Comment: Well, that's an unfortunate unclarity in the manual then: “Mallets [can be used for attacking]. In fortresses, use the mallet to free centurion warriors….” Thanks.